# Scroll hoziontally progressbar overflow container

Tags: jquery

I've seen a lot of tutorials for horizontal progress bars that progress whilst scrolling vertically, but I don't know nor could find any documentation on how to archive this whilst scrolling horizontally. So on a overflow-y: scroll container to have a progress bar underneath.

I currently have this:

```
<section class='topProducts'>
    <div class='grid-container full'>
        <div class='grid-x grid-margin-x marT120'>
            <div class='large-12 cell'>
                <h2 class='dtext marB50 center'>Top Sailing products</h2>
                <div class='topWrap rel' id='scrollprod'>
                    <div class='topinner'>
                        <?php echo do_shortcode('[products limit="6" columns="6" orderby="popularity" category="sailing" ]'); ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
                    </div>
        <div class='grid-x marT100'>
            <div class='large-12 cell'>
              <div class="progress-container">
                  <div class="progress-bar" id="myBar"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
    </section>

      $(".topWrap").scroll(function(){
        var winScroll = $(".topinner").width() - $(".topWrap").width();
        var width = $(".topinner").scrollRight();
        var scrolled = ((width / winScroll) * 100);
        $("#myBar").width(scrolled + "%");
      });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code.

```js
document
      .getElementById("scrollprod")
      .addEventListener("scroll", function () {
        var scrollerWrapper = document.getElementById("scrollprod");
        scrollPercent =
          (scrollerWrapper.scrollLeft /
            (scrollerWrapper.scrollWidth - scrollerWrapper.clientWidth)) *
          100;
        document.getElementById("myBar").style.width = scrollPercent + "%";
      });
```

```css
#scrollprod {
    overflow: auto;
  }
  .topinner {
    width: 2000px;
    background: #f333;
    padding: 20px;
  }

  .progress-bar {
    background: green;
    height: 6px;
    margin-top: 32px;
    width: 0;
  }
```

```html
<section class="topProducts">
  <div class="grid-container full">
    <div class="grid-x grid-margin-x marT120">
      <div class="large-12 cell">
        <h2 class="dtext marB50 center">Top Sailing products</h2>
        <div class="topWrap rel" id="scrollprod">
          <div class="topinner">Scoller Block</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-x marT100">
      <div class="large-12 cell">
        <div class="progress-container">
          <div class="progress-bar" id="myBar"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: You sir, are a genius! Thank you very much, I'd be high fiving you in person right now. :)